# Some cursor shapes small in custom Qt widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that uses a class inheriting from `QGraphicsView` in which I set the shape of the mouse cursor appropriate to the current position and mode.

Basically, I have a method that looks somewhat like

```
Qt::CursorShape MyClass::cursor_shape()
{
   if(<some condition>) return Qt::PointingHandCursor;
   if(<some other condition>) return Qt::ClosedHandCursor;
   ...
}
```

and in certain positions in the code, that is mostly mouse events, I call

```
setCursor(cursor_shape());
```

This works so far, safe for one problem:
For two cursor shapes, specifically `Qt::ClosedHandCursor`, `Qt::OpenHandCursor`, the cursor always has the minimal possible size for the system.
If the user has set the system cursor size (in Windows, the system setting "Mouse Pointer - Change pointer size") to something else than the minimum, this size is used for every other cursor shape, but not for those two.

I do not have any code that changes the cursor otherwise, and especially no code that manually sets cursor size.
Does anybody have an idea why this is the case and how I can change this?

From what I get when reading the `QCursor` constructor over bitmap, the cursor size is meant to come fully from the system and can't even be manually changed?

(I use Qt5, if that is relevant.)

Comment: Some cursor shapes may be available in the platform, other not. For those which are not Qt might provide the cursor shape by itself but this doesn't seem to consider the platform setup.

Comment: I just had a look into the mouse settings of my Windows 10. There seems to be in fact nothing available for `Qt::ClosedHandCursor`, `Qt::OpenHandCursor`.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Huh. So, should I rather use different cursors maybe? Which would you recommend? The particular situation is that I have some items that the user can grab and drag around, and I use them as the cursors when hovering over an item and when dragging it.

Comment: Not sure. The `Qt::PointingHandCursor` looks promising. Maybe, the `Qt::UpArrowCursor`. (It looks similar to the "Alternative Selection" in the Windows Mouse Properties.)